# Facebook API - Get friend lists with APP secret from open graph

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

is it possible to get the friend lists from an user with the APP secret(not with the access token) by using the open graph?

The User has already installed the APP.

Thanks in advance.

PS:
If I understand aright ... 
-> graph API = only works with the acces token
-> FQL = works with access token and app secret

Right?

Comment: Why ask such a question, instead of just *ing __testing__ it …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´ve never heard that you can use an app secret with FQL. Theoretically it is impossible to get the friend list from a user with the app secret only, because the app secret is the same for all users. There are only different access tokens (page token, app token, user token), but to get the friends of a user you will always need a user access token.

Btw, you don´t really need to worry about that if you are using one of those SDKs (PHP SDK, JS SDK...).
Also, it is best practice to use the Graph API if there is a possibility, and FQL only if there is non (good) way with the Graph API.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. My problem is that the user access token is decays after the user logged out on FB. Are there any solution for this problem?

Comment: no, that´s how it is supposed to work, for security/privacy reasons. but you have to create a login process in your app, if the user is not logged in on facebook it will present a login form anyway.